# Worth using ASP.NET profile class when using an ORM?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, asp.net-profiles

I am using Entity Framework 4.1 in an MVC 3 app.  I am wondering whether there is any real value in using the built-in ASP.NET profile system (in System.Web.Profile).  It's properties can't be queried efficiently, compared to simply creating a profile entity in my ORM model which can be LINQ-queried. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a question with a definitive answer, my personal preference is to avoid the built in Membership/Profile/Roles stuff and put it in my own datastore.

The exception perhaps would be the Membership cookie handling which can save you encrypting your auth cookie.